# Compiler does not detect changes when updating types or interfaces in types.ts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, react-typescript, typescript-eslint

*I'm working on several large projects using visual studio code, **react**, **typescript**, node, webpack etc.. that are unrelated but all have the same issue*

**For some components that use common types, I extract them into a type.ts file or interface.ts so I can import them to multiple components.**

---

### Problem:

I have an interesting issue where anytime I update these types or interfaces (such as changing a string type to number, adding, deleting or any type of update) my compiler does not pick up the changes and throws errors when I try to use the updated type or interface

### Only solution I currently have:

1. **Save file & Close vsc** (fully quit - reload does not work)
2. **Run npm start again** (after doing this, the new changes are picked up

### Does anyone know a better solution to this?

Such as a way to watch and apply changes in these files or some way to do the same with typescript linter or just **any thing that is automatic** - having to constantly close and open vsc + rerun servers has become very cumbersome

Comment: Have you tried just restarting VSCode TS server? See e.g. https://mikebifulco.com/posts/typescript-vscode-error-fix-last-resort